# jQuery UI draggable within map area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dictionary, draggable, area

I'm trying to make div container be draggable within image map area or check did we leave the area when the element is dragging,  here's example:

[image: the situation]

My first attempt was about listening mouseleave/mouseout events of the area, but they are calling everytime when I move the mouse over draggable element and not calling when I'm leaving the area with dragging this element.

Also I have tried to use {handler: $('map'),} and {handler: $('map area'),} options, but the element disappears when I start dragging.

Here is HTML code:

```
<div class="preview">
  <div class="image-wrapper ui-resizable ui-draggable" style="position: absolute;">
    <img src="img/image1.png" class="drag-image">
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
  </div>
  <img src="img/someimg.png" usemap="#imgmap2013112143545" class="bg-image" />
  <map id="imgmap2013112143545" name="imgmap2013112143545">
    <area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="117,75,144,94,229,113,276,113,358,89,381,75,395,123,316,203,281,245,269,239,247,239,238,241,234,246,179,192,141,158,112,121" href="/" target="">
  </map>
</div>
```

Now I'm thinking about some global mousemove event, that checks is the element dragging and did we leave the area.

Do you have any ideas how this can be solved otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to subscribe to the `drag` event of the `draggable` and do collision detection using the `offset` ui arguments relative to your collision area.

[Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag)

Comment: Thx for drag event, I didn't know about it. But how can I calculate collisions in non-rectangle area?